# How to write linq query with list of two joined tables a and B, then grouped by id of a, and with amount of joined rows from B

Tags: c#, linq

How to write Linq query with list of two joined tables A and B, then grouped by id of A, and with amount of joined rows from B

For example

```
class A{
   int Id,
   int BId,
   string AName
};

class B{
   int Id,
   string description
};
```

And to display as follows (after joins of A with B) A.Bid = B.Id

```
A Id |  count(Id) | AName
```

Frankly, I have to implement following query from PHP to LINQ. All dependencies are written in query below:  
select("asset.id as Id,asset.AssetBundleID as AssetBundleID,asset.GUID as GUID,asset.Name as Id,asset.Name as Id, asset.DisplayName as DisplayName,asset.Description as Description, asset.Category as Category,asset.TexturesSize as TexturesSize, asset.TexturesFileSize as TexturesFileSize, asset.OthersSize as OthersSize, asset.id as Id, asset.OthersFileSize as OthersFileSize, count(*) as InstancesCount")
->from("asset")
->join('Left Join',"assetinstance","`assetinstance`.`AssetId`=`asset`.`Id`")
->groupBy("asset.Id")

Comment: You have only 1 reference from A to B (`int BId`), how can the count be anything but 1?

Comment: I know that this is a quick example, but please at least make it correct, this is not a correct way to create classes in c#.

Comment: Can you give example tables of what data you are working with and what results you expect when your source tables have multiple rows?  Also, what have you already tried?

Comment: @rst I can have many rows in table A with the same BId, the join will be a.BId=b.Id

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class A 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int BId {get; set;}
    public string AName {get; set;}
}

public class B{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string description{get; set;}
}


public class Program
{
    private static List<A> _aList = new List<A>();  
    private static List<B> _bList = new List<B>();  

    public static void Main()
    {
        Seed();

        var query =
            from b in _bList
            group b by b.Id into g
            join a in _aList on g.FirstOrDefault().Id equals a.BId         
            select new { A_ID = a.Id, Cnt = g.Count(), AName = a.AName};

        Console.WriteLine("A_ID | count(Id) | AName");
        foreach(var row in query) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", new string[]{row.A_ID.ToString(), row.Cnt.ToString(), row.AName}));
        }
    }

    public static void Seed() 
    {       
        _aList.Add(new A{Id=1, BId=1, AName="A1"});
        _aList.Add(new A{Id=2, BId=1, AName="A2"});
        _aList.Add(new A{Id=3, BId=1, AName="A3"});
        _aList.Add(new A{Id=4, BId=2, AName="A4"});

        _bList.Add(new B{Id=1, description="B1"});
        _bList.Add(new B{Id=2, description="B2"});
    }
}
```

See my fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/NlAX5V

Comment: Almost OK, but not all rows are returned becuase of join, that only a members appears if b exists. If member in b does't exists, I have no member from a             _aList.Add(new A { Id = 1, BId = 1, AName = "A1" });
            _aList.Add(new A { Id = 2, BId = 1, AName = "A2" });
            _aList.Add(new A { Id = 3, BId = 1, AName = "A3" });
            _aList.Add(new A { Id = 4, BId = 3, AName = "A4" });

            _bList.Add(new B { Id = 1, description = "B1" });
            _bList.Add(new B { Id = 2, description = "B2" });

Answer (score 0):

```
var result= (from A in ListA
             join B in List B
             on A.ID equals B.ID
             select new {A,B})
             .GroupBy(x=>x.A.Id)
             .Select(x=>new
              {
                ID=x.Key
                count=x.Count(),
                AName=x.Select(z=>z.A.AName)
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, the same thing as above. If b member doesn't exist, I'll have no a row, for example _bList.Add(new B{Id=3, description="B3"}); instead of _bList.Add(new B{Id=2, description="B2"});

Comment: More over join needs to be on A.BId= B.Id